# How to install the correct intel driver onto Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, intel

My laptop is kinda sluggish but I think it has to do with the graphics.

The whole system freezes when trying to encode or transcode a movie.

All my research leads to the valleyview Gen7 graphics.

I opened additional drivers and nothing shows up.

Comment: I don't know that this will help you, but I suggest you check the Intel Open source Site to download the Proprietary drivers:https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8

Comment: @MarcosRocha The Intel drivers are open source, not proprietary, even if you download the latest version. However, since ValleyView came out in 2012, the kernel and xorg in 14.04 would already have the official drivers that support the graphics. Newer versions might possibly have some minor bug fixes, but I doubt any that would have an effect on the "issues" mentioned here. It's an Atom, so probably only has 2GB RAM, and is already fairly slow to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what laptop you have, but I suspect your issue has nothing to do with the graphics drivers. Ubuntu 14.04 already comes with Intel graphics drivers. Intel develops these drivers in the open and in the upstream kernel and Xorg trees.

The system freezing when trying to encode or transcode a movie, is likely due to simply overloading the system. Valley View is Intel Atom, which is their very low power X86 processor line. If you are trying to encode or transcode a movie in very high quality, you are probably running out of memory and hitting swap (if you even have any), probably using up all processing resources to perform the work, and depending on what type of hard drive you have, the disk I/O will bring your system to a crawl.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Atom processors are too weak for much more than browsing and checking email.

Comment: thanks guys for all the feedback i verry much appreciate it :)

Comment: so i guess in short just tell my freind not to encode or transcode on a intell atom ...right ....lol :)  thanx   again for all the help

Comment: againg thanks for all the help  @MarcosRocha  " actually the machine is not a speed demon but its not that slow either i upgraded the ram for him to 8gb  but you are probably right about the bug fixes ill look into that ...."

Comment: the machine actually runs decent as long as im not transcoding or encoding ...but the really weird thing to me is  this same machine was actually working and even encoding movie fine before he deleted his home dir the first time then i reinstalled ubuntu again and it hasnt been right since ...  but thanks again im glad i have this site and people like all of you to help me thank you so so much

Comment: Please click the "accept this answer" link for this answer then. The best way to thank people, is to accept the answers they give, so that they are given the appropriate reputation credit for it. :)